# How to solve this partial differential equation for $f$?

Tags: differential-equations

I want Mathematica to solve for the function $f$.

$f$ satisfies the following constraints.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) = y$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = x$

$f(0,0)=0$

It would seem obvious that $f(x,y) = x y$

Yet I cannot coax Mathematica into returning this result.

Here is my attempt. 
Mathematica just returns it unevaluated. What am I missing?

```
DSolve[
    {
       x == D[f[x, y] , y]
     , y == D[f[x, y] , x]
     , f[0, 0] == 0
    }

, {f[x, y], f[x, y]}
, {x, y}
]
```

Comment: A partial differential equations needs more than a pointwise condition `f[0,0]==0` I think. But Mathematica can't solve with modified conditions `f[x,0]==0,f[0,y]==0`either.

Comment: The following does the trick: `DSolve[Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] == {y, x}, f[x, y], {x, y}]` - It seems that `DSolve` wants a single differential equation instead of separate ones, even if that "single" differential equation is just one with several components

Comment: Alternative `DSolve[{1 == Derivative[1, 1][f][x, y] }, f[x, y], {x, y}]`

Comment: Fixed in V12.2 for the PDE.  The BVP still returns no solution, no matter what order the terms of the PDE are put in.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141716/solve-a-simple-system-of-partial-differential-equations

Answer (score 9):

Strangely the solver works when the derivative is on the left-hand side of the equals sign.

```
DSolve[
    {
       D[f[x, y] , y] == x
     , D[f[x, y] , x] == y
    }        

, {f[x, y], f[x, y]}
, {x, y}
]
```

Although I am rather partial to @Lukas Lang's gradient form which I am also pasting here for my future self's convenience.

```
DSolve[

     Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] == {y, x}

    ,f[x, y]
    , {x, y}
]
```

Comment: Interestingly, `DSolve[{y, x} == Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], f[x, y], {x, y}]` also returns unevaluated.  `DSolve` seems particularly fickle, when attempting to solve pairs of linear, inhomogeneous PDEs.

Comment: It does not find the solution if given boundary conditions, though. -- The problem is somewhat of a special case since $f_x=a,\ f_y=b$ has no solution unless $a_y=b_x$. And in the parser (in V12.0), only a special syntactic form is matched to a solution method.

Answer (score 1):

Not including boundary condition seems to be good enough:

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, y], y] == x, D[f[x, y], x] == y}, f[x, y], {x, y}]
(* {{f[x, y] -> x y + C[1]}} *)
```

Comment: This solution is already given in Conor's old answer....If you have V12.2 (or maybe V12.1), try the problem in the OP without the BC; then it will be solved in the new version of Mma.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware Conor's old answer presented this!